# How to find out a cookie was set by javascript or server code?

Tags: php, cookies

I have some special cookies. I need those cookie was set by server code only. So I need to find out that cookie was set by javascript or server code. Is it possible?

Comment: A cookie's a cookie. There's nothing about them says "I'm a server cookie" and "I'm a javascript cookie". You'd have to keep track of which cookies are set by the server, as the client's completely out of your control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically speaking you could not determine this information.  One way to try would be to hash the value out using like sha1/md5 and use a session on the server side to store the same value and assert the hashes match.

Could you explain a bit more about what you are trying to do though and perhaps some sort of solution is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has almost ten years but i'm including my 2 cents just in case. ;)

As Chris and Marc B answered, there is no way you can differentiate from where a cookie is created. This is true to this day.

To solve the problem of not allowing Javascript to get a specific cookie: you can set a cookie as `HttpOnly` and supporting browsers will not allow it to be set from Javascript, this will not prevent many of the ways of tampering with the cookie such as Man in the Middle attacks but is useful to make things a bit harder.

To set the default session cookie as `HttpOnly` in PHP, make sure you have this in your `php.ini` file (and make sure of it by running `phpinfo();`):

```
session.cookie_httponly = On
```

To set a `HttpOnly` cookie from your application:

```
// Do it with
setcookie($name, $value, $expires, $path, $domain, $secure, true);

// OR
setrawcookie($name, $value, $expires, $path, $domain, $secure, true);

// OR with PHP 7.3+
setcookie($name, $value, ['httponly' => true]);

// OR with PHP 7.3+
setrawcookie($name, $value, ['httponly' => true]);

// OR by sending the raw header
//   Set-Cookie: <name>=<value>[; <Max-Age>=<age>][; expires=<date>][; domain=<domain_name>][; path=<some_path>][; Secure][; HttpOnly]
header("Set-Cookie: {$name}={$value}; HttpOnly", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am probably late here but if you are just interested in finding out if the cookie is set via javascript or the server side then you can simply disable javascript in you dev tools and see if the cookie is set or not. If it is not set with javascript disabled then it is most likely set via server.

You can disable javascript in the preferences of your dev console:
[(Settings > preferences > Debugger)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maBhV.png)

Note: This would tackle most common cases but of course if the cookie is set via some AJAX call to the server thats being made via javascript then this might give you false positive result